# How to fetch data from nodejs in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

Not calling the nodejs restapi from angular services.

users.component.ts

```
    editUser(){
    const updatedUser ={
      _id: this._id,
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      mobile: this.mobile
    }
    console.log(updatedUser)
    this.usersService.updateUser(updatedUser)
    this.readUsers();
  }
```

users.service.ts

```
 updateUser(updatedUser){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/edit/' + updatedUser._id, updatedUser).pipe(
      map(res => res.json())
    )
  }
```

nodejs restapi

userRoutes.js

```
  const edituser = []
router.post('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('fromEditRoute')
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id : req.params.id}, req.body)
    .then(result => {
        edituser.push(result)
        res.json(edituser)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({message: 'An Error Occured'});
    })
    console.log('hello')
})
```

> console.log() in routes is not even printed.

Every help will be appreciated, Thank You!!

Comment: semicolons are good :)  Q: Can you communicate with any API in your NodeJS server?  For example, can you use Postman with any GET or POST in the api?

Comment: In postman Api is working..

Comment: do you have a call to `updateUser` with subscription? show us the call to this function

Comment: can you share your proxy.conf.js/json file?

Comment: I forget .subscribe(). Thanks community. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.usersService.updateUser(updatedUser).subscibe(console.log);
```

You need to subscribe to fire the request. Observables are lazy by default. Unless you subscribe the execution doesn't start.

Comment: It worked, how can i forget subscribe...Thank you for help.

Comment: np. it happened to me also in past :P. Please upvote if it has helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

users.component.ts

```
   editUser(){
        const updatedUser ={
          _id: this._id,
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          mobile: this.mobile
        }
        console.log(updatedUser)
        this.usersService.updateUser(updatedUser).subscribe((response: any)=> {
        console.log(response);
       })
        this.readUsers();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because you are not subscribing to the API call. Pipe wont subscribe to the observerble. Once you do the subscription only it will execute the call. Otherwise it will hang without giving an response. Thats why you dont get the anything as the response

Change your user service as follows:

```
updateUser(updatedUser){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/edit/' + updatedUser._id, updatedUser).subscibe(console.log);
  }
```